# Why this makefile exmaple doesn't show make: 'xxxx' is up to date.?

Tags: makefile

I am reading this https://makefiletutorial.com/ makefile tutorial.

With this exmaple:

```
some_file:
    echo "This line will only print once"
    touch some_file
```

> This file will make some_file the first time, and the second time notice it’s already made, resulting in `make: 'some_file' is up to date.`

---

While with this example:

```
some_binary: ../headers blah.h
    touch some_binary

../headers:
    mkdir ../headers

blah.h:
    touch ../headers/blah.h

clean:
    rm -rf ../headers
    rm -f some_binary
```

Why don't I  get `'xxxx' is up to date` notice? My output is:

```
tianhe@tianhe-windy:~/Desktop/learnMake/lala$ make 
mkdir ../headers
touch ../headers/blah.h
touch some_binary
tianhe@tianhe-windy:~/Desktop/learnMake/lala$ make 
touch ../headers/blah.h  
touch some_binary
tianhe@tianhe-windy:~/Desktop/learnMake/lala$
```

I expect to get `xxx is up to date` notice the second time I run `make`, just like the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: because `blah.h` is not the same thing as `../headers/blah.h`.

So a rule like this:

```
blah.h:
        touch ../headers/blah.h
```

is wrong: the target tells make "this recipe will create a file named `blah.h`", but the recipe actually creates a file named `../headers/blah.h`.

So the next time make runs, it looks for `blah.h` again: if it was found then you'd get a message saying that things were up to date.  But since it's not found, make will try to make it again because it's clearly not up to date (since it doesn't exist).

Comment: ah, great answer. So that's why add `vpath %.h ../headers ../other-directory` at the top will give `xxx is up to date`. Thank you MadMad

Comment: In general it's not going to work to use `vpath`/`VPATH` to find files that are _created_.  Those are meant to find source files (source in the sense that they aren't built by make).  It can work in some specific situations but needs to be considered carefully.

Comment: But adding `vpath %.h ../headers ../other-directory` stops `blah.h` target from executing. Doesn't it mean `make` find `blah.h` directly?

Comment: Btw, for the makefile example in my question (without `vpath`), is it because that `make` treat `../headers` as a file or directory, so `make` doesn't execute `../headers` target the second time I run it?

Comment: If you want to understand VPATH better and my comment above you can read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/  Since you are buiilding a header file here it's not as important because make doesn't need to find the header, only the compiler needs to find it.

Comment: Correct.  If a target has no prerequisites defined in the makefile, then all make can do is check whether it exists or not.  There's no prerequisite to compare its timestamp to, so if the file exists make decides it must be up to date.

Comment: Note, however, you should almost never use a directory as a prerequisite because the modification times on directories are updated whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed in that directory.  This means that any target that depends on the directory will be rebuilt whenever any file in that directory is added, removed, or renamed; that's rarely what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will keep that in mind and read it later when I need it.